# dropboxd on linux server has stopped syncing

Tags: linux, dropbox, webfaction

I installed the dropbox linux client on a server and everything was working fine for a few months. Then on 18/5/2014 it stopped syncing for some reason. I suspected the server had been restarted so I restarted dropbox:

```
~/bin/dropbox.py start
Starting Dropbox...Done!
```

The problem is it looks like it's syncing but isn't:

```
[willemmerson@web385 media]$ ~/bin/dropbox.py status
Downloading file list...
Syncing (317 files remaining)
Uploading 317 files...

[willemmerson@web385 media]$ ~/bin/dropbox.py filestatus
email:           unwatched
header_images:   unwatched
homepage_images: unwatched
paintings:       unwatched
```

It never goes past 317 files and for some reason it says those folders are unwatched

Comment: I see the `media` named folder you're using for sycning. Does dropboxd correctly configured for that folder? It may watching the default `Dropbox` folder right now.

Comment: Hi, turned out I just needed to update everything

Comment: I had the same issue.  My problem was that I was start dropbox in a wrong user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the newest version of dropboxd and the python script and restarting seemed to fix it:

install linux client here:
http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment

install python script to control it here:
http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli

Comment: Process I followed: `dropbox update`, `dropbox stop`, `dropbox start`, `dropbox status`. Walked away for a few minutes. Came back and found this message printed several times: "Unable to monitor entire Dropbox folder hierarchy. Please run "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf; sudo sysctl -p" and restart Dropbox to fix the problem." I did exactly that, and now Dropbox appears to be working properly.

Comment: Thank you. Dropbox update and restart made it wake up again. Also, I had to update fs.inotify.max_user_watches=100000 to the number of files pending due to huge amount of files I moved into the folder recently. It seems to be syncing now.